# basic counter to increment a link is not displaying properly in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a number of steps and I have a counter that I would like to increment as the block iterates through the steps. More specifically, if its media type is "excel" or  anything else I would like it to say step 2, step 3, step 4 etc.   However in the view it only says step 1, step 1, step 1 - it does not properly increment.  What is wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <% @step_list.each do |i| %>

 <% x = 0 %>
  <% case %>
  <% when i.media_type == 'video' %>
   <% x += 1 %>
        <li class="active">

              <span>Video</span>
          </a>
        </li>


  <% when i.media_type == 'excel' %>
    <% x += 1 %>
        <li class="">

              <span>Step <%= x %> </span>

        </li>

  <% else %>

  <% x += 1 %>

        <li class="dark-nav ">
              <span>Step <%= x %></span>

        </li>

  <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem in your code is** that you initialize the variable `x` in each loop, you should initialize it to zero **before** your loop.

**To solve this**, You can refactor this with the method `.each_with_index do |element, i|`:

```
<% @step_list.each_with_index do |step, i| %>
  <% case step.media_type %>
  <% when 'video' %>
    <li class="active">
      <span>Video</span>
    </li>
  <% when 'excel' %>
    <li class="">
      <span>Step <%= i %></span>
    </li>
  <% else %>
    <li class="dark-nav ">
      <span>Step <%= i %></span>
    </li>
  <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) ?

```
[1, 2, 3].each_with_index do |n, i|
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You reset your x each time, try that :

```
<% @step_list.each_with_index do |i,index| %>
  <% case i.media_type %>
  <% when 'video' %>
        <li class="active">

              <span>Video</span>
          </a>
        </li>

  <% when 'excel' %>
        <li class="">
          <span>Step <%= index %> </span>
        </li>

  <% else %>
        <li class="dark-nav ">
              <span>Step <%= index  %></span>

        </li>
  <% end %>   
<% end %> 
<% end %>
```